# MSSQL Single user mode block

Tags: sql-server

I am a web design so I dont understand almost nothing of servers and stuff.

I was working with MSSQL Server and ASP.NET to create a form that save its information in a database. But it was failing because my account in MSSQL was asking "Please change your password" because it had a "Enforce password expiration". I needed the "sa" account password to change it (I was using SQL Authentication) but I didnt know about the "sa" password.

I searched in Internet and I found out about "single user mode". I  added the "-m" to the startup parameters but I am so stupid that I forgot about stop sql agent.

Result? I cant use MSSQL now. Neither with administration account. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I am so sorry about this and thanks so much to who try to help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this via configuration manager? You should be able to just edit the startup parameters again and restart the service, and it should come back online in multi user mode.

Edit: Just checked and this definitely works.

1. Launch SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Right click your SQL Instance > Properties
3. On the Startup Parameters tab, remove the -m flag youve added
4. Click OK, OK to apply
5. Right click the service and click restart

You will be back in multi user mode.

Comment: Thanks, thanks so much! It really work. I had already done the 1-4 steps and I was worrying because it wasnt working. You really saved my life. :)